# Reportlab to consolidate reports to one PDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, reportlab

I am writing a program to automate our reports. I found the following [Script](https://www.calazan.com/a-simple-python-program-for-exporting-a-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pdf-table-using-reportlab/) that converts data to a pdf and works well. I have modified it slightly but not too much. I am able to generate all of the reports individually but cannot seem to get them to all print to one pdf.

Here is an example of formatting one data set from the db call and how the script is invoked.

```
def datafilter(tuna):

    data = []

    for name, number, count in tuna:
        data.append({'name': name,
                     'number': number,
                     'count': count})

    fields = (
        ('name', 'Location'),
        ('number', 'Number'),
        ('count', 'Call Count'),
    )

    doc1 = DataToPdf(fields, data, sort_by=('name', 'DESC'),
                    title='Main Number Called')
    doc2 = DataToPdf(fields1, data1, sort_by=('name', 'DESC'),
                    title='Main Number Called')
    doc = doc1, doc2
    doc.export('Main_Calls.pdf')
```

I've tried manipulating that `doc.export` call every which way but cannot get it too work. I suspect I may need to create a loop somewhere. When the doc variable is created I have tried stuffing my data in there as a tuple but then error out saying 'export method can't take tuple'

Can someone at least point me in the right direction. I am still newer to this.

EDIT** Traceback

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /root/PycharmProjects/ReportApp/FML/apendhelp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/ReportApp/FML/apendhelp.py", line 53, in <module>
    masterin()
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/ReportApp/FML/apendhelp.py", line 50, in masterin
    datafilter1(main_bk, top_bk)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/ReportApp/FML/apendhelp.py", line 38, in datafilter1
    poop.export('mater.pdf')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'export'
```

Comment: Your `poop` in the error is a `tuple` (that's exactly what the error message says), and not a `DataToPdf` object that it should be. I'm fairly sure your small example could not produce the same error on that line. Do make sure that your dummy example posted still leads to the same error (this is "C" in "MCVE")

Comment: Your right sorry just caught that I will edit it a little but the 'doc' variable I have converted to a tuple

Comment: If you "converted it to a tuple", why do you expect it to have a `.export` method? Does the page you linked to and from where you got the code convert it to a tuple? See the problem?

Comment: The page I linked too has the export method defined.  No I think I only half understand the problem. I am somewhat of a noob. I understand that it doesnt want a tuple and i have tried a bunch of work arounds but i am not good enough to get it :(

Comment: `doc.export`  is a method of class `DataToPdf`. `(doc1,doc2).export` would be a method of class `tuple`, because `(doc1,doc2)` is a tuple, regardless of what's inside. Tuples don't have an `export` method, simple as that. You can only call `.export` on `DataToPdf` objects. If you want to put two things into the same pdf file: well, you have a problem you need to figure out, but you'll likely have to use a single call of `.export`, and that on an object of `DataToPdf`.

Comment: Thats basically my hell right now. Is there a way I can extend the export method to append each doc object so that I can have one full pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I wasn't able to actually get it to make 1 solid pdf but I did find a work around. I set up one master button to generate all the reports. Then a merge button which will scan the destination folder, find all pdfs and append them together into one master pdf by using PyPDF2's PdfFileMerger. Here is the code if anyone else needs this.

```
def pdf_merger():
    files_dir = '/root/PycharmProjects/ReportApp/FML/Pdf_Docs'

    pdf_files = [f for f in os.listdir(files_dir) if f.endswith("pdf")]
    merger = PdfFileMerger()

    for filename in pdf_files:
        merger.append(PdfFileReader(os.path.join(files_dir, filename), "rb"))

    merger.write(os.path.join(files_dir, "merged_full.pdf"))
    merger.close()
```

Obviously you need to edit the `files_dir` variable to fit your needs but otherwise this should work well.